# Does named shared memory imply IO and impact the performance?

Tags: ipc, shared-memory, mmap, file-descriptor, temporary-files

I need to share many memory buffers between two processes.
I'm trying to use mmap to archive it. According to the doc, only with the MAP_ANONYMOUS flag, no file descriptor is needed, therefore I wouldn't worry about physical IO taking place.

But anonymous mapping only can be used within single process, I need some names to identify each buffer between processes!
Therefor I have to use shm_open to create a file descriptor before calling mmap.

After calling shm_open, a file would appear at `/dev/shm`, I'm worrying about that some disk IO invoked. I know that is a temporary file system, but I'm confusing where it is stored at last?

Is there another way, we can create Named Shared Memory without a file in Linux?

In addition, I need "lazy-allocation" and "full-zero initialization". I'm interested in whether those still be guaranteed with "Named Shared Memory" or not.

Comment: Anonymous mapped memory can be shared between a parent and child process, if that helps.

Comment: It is memory, but all memory is paged, so all memory including this requires page-file space somewhere, and implies I/O if paging occurs.